# Manually calling destructor before delete

Tags: c++, destructor, undefined-behavior, delete-operator

```
auto obj = new Object;
obj->~Object();
delete obj;
```

I know it's unusual, but is it defined behavior? Can it cause any surprising problems?

Comment: In case it's not entirely obvious from WhiZTiM's answer, the reason why it's undefined is because it would call *two* destructors for the same object in a row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only do that **if** you replace the destroyed object pointed by `obj` with a new object as per:

```
auto obj = new Object;
obj->~Object();

new (obj) Object();
delete obj;
```

Otherwise, you invoke Undefined Behavior.

---

You should understand that:

- `new` calls `operator new` to obtain memory, **then** calls the provided construtor to create the object
- `delete` calls the destructor of the object, **then** calls `operator delete` to "return" memory.

---

---

EDIT: As Bo Persson pointed out, its not a good idea if you can't provide exception guarantees

Comment: If you *successfully* replace the object. Should the constructor throw, you are still toast.

Comment: If it were necessary that an object's destruction occur at a time before memory gets released, would there be any way of telling C++ "This pointer identifies allocated storage used by an object which has been destructed but not yet deleted; please release the storage without calling the destructor"?

Comment: @supercat, yes... But its going to require more work. While you can explicitly call `operator delete(obj)` on the pointer, it would fail in cases where there is a [*class-specific* `operator delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete#Class-specific_overloads). When the `delete` *expression* calls `operator delete (...)`, the standard mandates it to check for *class-specific* overloads first. But when you explicitly call `operator delete` in your code, this [doesn't happen](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e4c76a444a8d8cf).

Comment: @supercat, [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29cea8bbc5cc3f4e) is the **regular** case where class-specific overloads are checked. [Double destructor hence UB](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b656461c8a9a2d8) is what happens in OP's case. [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e4c76a444a8d8cf) is what happens when you explicitly call it yourself, in contrast with the **regular** case. The right way would be [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04c21d56adcd5ff4), however, what of a case where you don't know whether there was a *class-specific* overload? More complexity?

Answer (score 1):

It is Undefined Behaviour to cause an objects destructor to be invoked twice. You are not following the rules and the compiler is allowed to do whatever it pleases with your code. Just *don't do that*.

Answer (score 0):

If we go strictly by the language of standard, your code is cause for undefined behavior and will cause problems.

However, I will be very surprised if any platform will run into any problems with the following:

```
struct Foo {};

void testFoo()
{
   Foo* foo = new Foo();
   foo->~Foo();
   foo->~Foo();
   foo->~Foo();
   foo->~Foo();
   foo->~Foo();
   foo->~Foo();
   foo->~Foo();
   delete foo;
}
```

On the other hand, I will be very surprised if any platform can execute the following without running into problems.

```
struct Bar {std::string s;};

void testBar()
{
   Bar* bar = new Bar{"test"};
   bar->~Bar();
   delete bar;
}
```